# Paypal Shipping Dropdown Default Method

Tags: html, button, paypal, default

I have 2 shipping options set up in my PayPal profile shipping calculator, Standard Shipping and Pickup. I want Standard to be the default for my "Buy Now" button. In the dropdown that the buyer gets on checkout, the default is Pickup (which I have as a $0 option). I can't find how to change it so that Standard comes up as the default. ("Pickup" will be the exception and should be selected with intent.) Is there HTML line I can put in the button code, or a button "variable" that I can use to change the default shipping method so that it does not just jump on the cheapest choice?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Website Payments Standard Buy Now and Add to cart buttons, there is not a way to do this.  It defaults to the cheapest option available.  The only way that you would be able to set a default shipping, would be to use the Instant Update Callback API.  This would work for setting the default shipping with the cart upload method or with Express Checkout.  You can see information on the API [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/callback-api-operation-nvp) as well as in the developers guide [here](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf) on page 55.   Also below is an simple example of a PHP Callback script I use for testing sometimes, if it helps you to better understand it.  I am not sure what language your are going to code your script in.

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req = "&$key=$value";
}

// Populate variables into local variables
$method = $_POST['METHOD'];
$version = $_POST['CALLBACKVERSION'];
$token = $_POST['TOKEN'];
$currencycode = $_POST['CURRENCYCODE'];
$localecode = $_POST['LOCALECODE'];
$street = $_POST['SHIPTOSTREET'];
$street2 = $_POST['SHIPTOSTREET2'];
$city = $_POST['SHIPTOCITY'];
$state = $_POST['SHIPTOSTATE'];
$country = $_POST['SHIPTOCOUNTRY'];
$zip = $_POST['SHIPTOZIP'];

// Setting shipping based on country first
// Then setting shipping based on state if the country is U.S.
// Echo response back to PayPal
if ($country == "US"){
    if ($state == "NE"){
    echo "METHOD=CallbackResponse&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=UPS&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=Ground&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=3.00&L_TAXAMT0=1.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=9.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true";
    }elseif ($state == "KS"){ 
    echo "METHOD=CallbackResponse&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=UPS&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=Ground&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=6.00&L_TAXAMT0=12.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=81.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true";
    }else{
    echo "METHOD=CallbackResponse&NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS=1&CALLBACKVERSION=61";
    }
}elseif ($country == "CA"){
    echo "METHOD=CallbackResponse&NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS=1&CALLBACKVERSION=61";
}else{
    echo "METHOD=CallbackResponse&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=UPS&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=Ground&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=10.00&L_TAXAMT0=2.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=2.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to know I wasn't missing something basic in the standard buttons. I'm afraid setting up an API is over my head though. (IANA programmer; can do html and fill in forms like the button maker and WP plugins.) Might be a learning opportunity. I'll work with it starting with what you pointed me to.

Comment: I added an example of a callback script I use for testing.  Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks again, and I'll start working on what to do with the code you provided.